# how to write ostringstream directly to cout

Tags: c++

If I have an `std::ostringstream` object called `oss`, I understand I can do `std::cout << oss.str()` to print out the string. But doing `oss.str()` would result in the returned string being copied. Is there a way to print directly the underlying `streambuf`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26):

Not if you're using [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). The underlying buffer for this cannot be read from (hence the `o` in `ostringstream`), so you have to rely on the implementation to do it for you, via `str()`.

However, if you use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (note the lack of `o`), then the underlying buffer is readable, and `basic_ostream`'s have a special overload forreading from buffers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss1;
    ss1 << "some " << 111605 << " stuff" << std::flush;

    std::cout << ss1.rdbuf() << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss1.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> some 111605 stuff
>   some 111605 stuff

([Example derived from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442561/87234).)

This copies directly from the underlying buffer, without an intermediate copy.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works. I also found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009809/query-stdostringstream-content/10010160#10010160 where ostream is used to achieve the same thing. I was just wondering what's the difference between using ostream and stringstream. which one is more performant?

Comment: @WinstonHuang: You have to profile it to find out which is more performant. I doubt it's any faster though, and it's certainly more complicated than just using `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Tried on gcc 9.1.0. `std::cout << ss1.str()` is faster anyway. (stdout was redirected to _/dev/null_).

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4ffa641487aa4cf